# I2C Bitbanging in Raspberry pi

Tags: linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, i2c

We are using `raspberry pi` in one of our projects; in the same we want to use the i2c to interface touch screen. As i2c in pi shall not support clock stretching planning to use the i2c bit banging. I am following the procedure as given in the link;
[I2C-GPIO](http://lwn.net/Articles/230571/)

I am unable activate the `i2c` on `gpio`. I get the following error

```
i2c-gpio: probe of i2c-gpio.0 failed with error -22
```

Regards
Suman

Comment: How are you registering the `i2c_gpio_platform_data` struct? Have you installed i2c-tools, and verified the bus is working?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com ? I don't know if I'm wrong, but this does not seem to be about the programming itself.

Answer (score 2):

I recall getting similar errors like this when I was first getting started with the PI, have you enabled I2C on your PI? I'm not sure which distro your running so I'll just assume that you installed  Raspbian Wheezy.

I2C is disabled by default on Wheezy The process to enable it is pretty simple but, I was not expecting it to be disabled by default so I was disappointed when the first I2C calls were bombing. The example you posted didnt mention enabling I2C either so that's where I would begin.

Check out this fine walk-through on how to enable I2C.  http://www.skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/575